# Retrieving bucketting value in WITH statement for subsequent SELECT

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I have several tables with bucketing applied. It can work great when I specify the bucket/partition parameter upfront in my SELECT query, however when I retrieve the bucket value I need from a different table - within a WITH select statement, Hive/Athena seems to no longer use the optimisation, and searches the entire database instead.  I would like to learn if there is a way to write my query properly to maintain the optimisation.

For a simple example, I have two tables:

Table1

```
category | categoryid
---------+-----------
mass     | 1
```

Table2

```
categoryid | index | value
-----------+-------+------
1          | 0     | 15
1          | 1     | 10
1          | 2     | 7
```

The bucketed/clustered column is `categoryid`.  I have a single `category` ('mass') and would like to retrieve the `value`'s that correspond with the `category` I have.  So I have designed my SELECT like this:

```
WITH dataset AS (
       SELECT categoryid
       FROM Table1
       WHERE category='mass'
     )
SELECT index,value
  FROM Table2, dataset
  WHERE Table2.categoryid=dataset.categoryid
```

This will run, but will search the entire database it seems, because Hive doesn't know the `categoryid` for bucketing before commencing the search? If I swap out the final `Table2.categoryid=dataset.categoryid` for `Table2.categoryid=1` then it will search only the fraction of the db.

So is there some way of writing this query to ensure Hive doesn't search more buckets in the second table than it has to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Athena is based on Presto. Unless there is some modification in Athena in this area (and I think there currently isn't), this cannot be made to work in single query.

Recommended workaround: issue one query to gather `dataset.categoryid` values. Pass them as constant to your main query:

```
WITH dataset AS (
       SELECT category
       FROM Table1
       WHERE category='mass'
     )
SELECT index,value
  FROM Table2, dataset
  WHERE Table2.categoryid = dataset.categoryid
    AND Table2.categoryid IN ( <all possible values> );
```

This is going to be improved with the additional of [Dynamic Filtering in Presto](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/52), that the Presto Community is working on currently.

Comment: Ah it's based on Presto, my mistake.  Thanks for the answer - while I had hoped it was just me doing something wrong, it's good to be told that the answer is simply it's not implemented yet.   Good to see the github issue too - will keep an eye on that.  Thanks heaps!